# c#, задача по условным операторам

Tags: c#, if, тернарный-оператор

Прохожу обучение на программиста. Прошу помочь в решении задачи по с# с использованием условных операторов. Сейчас изучаем тернарный оператор ? и if else

**Задание:**

Напишите программу, которая принимает на вход 10 целых чисел и
выводит на экран:

- количество чисел, больших 10; Для решения используйте тернарный оператор.
- количество чисел, меньших -10; не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы программа посчитала количество нужных чисел (и в случае с больше и в случае с меньше)
- среднее арифметическое всех чисел; - сделано
- максимальное и минимальное значения в списке. - хотела использовать класс Math, min и max, но они вмещают в себя только 2 значения, если сравнивать числа друг с другом, то это будет сравнений 100

Начало кода ниже

```
        Console.WriteLine("Введите первое число");
        int number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите второе число");
        int number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите третье число");
        int number3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите четвертое число");
        int number4 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите пятое число");
        int number5 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите шестое число");
        int number6 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите седьмое число");
        int number7 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите восьмое число");
        int number8 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите девятое число");
        int number9 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите десятое число");
        int number10 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int summ = number1 + number2 + number3 + number4 + number5 + number6 + number7 + number8 + number9 + number10;

        Console.WriteLine($"Сумма всех десяти чисел будет {summ}");

        //Кол-во чисел,больше 10

        //if ( number1 <-10 )
        //{

        //}

        Console.WriteLine($"Среднее арифметическое всех десяти чисел будет {summ/10}");
```

Comment: Запомните одно очень важное правило в программировании - DRY (Don’t repeat yourself) - не повторяй себя. Если вы видите, что вам надо множество одинаковых объектов, то используйте коллекции/массивы. В коде не должно быть повторений, особенно `number...`. Имея на руках коллекцию, сделать все нужные вам операции очень просто простым перебором.

Comment: Помочь в чем именно? Конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: Сравнений будет не 100, а 9. Находите max первого и второго числа, назовём его x.  Далее находите max третьего числа и x. И так далее. / Но лучше освойте коллекции и циклы.

Comment: Они же могли (наверняка) колекции/массивы/циклы ещё не изучать...

Comment: думаю, что среднее арифметическое у вас считается неправильно. Средняя будет равна 0,5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за помощь. Разобрались.
Вот конечный код.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Введите первое целое число");
        int number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите второе целое число");
        int number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите третье целое число");
        int number3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите четвертое целое число");
        int number4 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите пятое целое число");
        int number5 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите шестое целое число");
        int number6 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите седьмое целое число");
        int number7 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите восьмое целое число");
        int number8 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите девятое целое число");
        int number9 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Введите десятое целое число");
        int number10 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int summ = number1 + number2 + number3 + number4 + number5 + number6 + number7 + number8 + number9 + number10;

        Console.WriteLine($"Сумма всех десяти чисел будет {summ}");

        int counter = 0;
        int result;

        result = number1 >10 ? ++counter: counter;
        result = number2 >10 ? ++counter :counter;
        result = number3 > 10 ? ++counter : counter;
        result = number4 > 10 ? ++counter : counter;
        result = number5 > 10 ? ++counter : counter;
        result = number6 > 10 ? ++counter : counter;
        result = number7 > 10 ? ++counter : counter;
        result = number8 > 10 ? ++counter : counter;
        result = number9 > 10 ? ++counter : counter;
        result = number10 > 10 ? ++counter : counter;

        Console.WriteLine($"Количество чисел, больше 10 будет {result}");

        int counter2 = 0;
        int result2;

        if (number1 <-10)
        {
            result2 = ++counter2;
            Console.WriteLine($"Количество чисел, меньше -10 будет {result2}");
        }

        if (number2 < -10)
        {
            result2 = ++counter2;
            
        }

        if (number3 < -10)
        {
            result2 = ++counter2;
            
        }

        if (number4 < -10)
        {
            result2 = ++counter2;
            
        }

        if (number5 < -10)
        {
            result2 = ++counter2;
            
        }

        if (number6 < -10)
        {
            result2 = ++counter2;
           
        }

        if (number7 < -10)
        {
            result2 = ++counter2;
            
        }

        if (number8 < -10)
        {
            result2 = ++counter2;
            
        }

        if (number9 < -10)
        {
            result2 = ++counter2;
            
        }


        if (number10 < -10)
        {
            result2 = ++counter2;
            
        }

        else
        {
            result2 = counter2;
            
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Количество чисел, меньше -10 будет {result2}");

        Console.WriteLine($"Среднее арифметическое всех десяти чисел будет {summ/10}");

        int resultMax1 = Math.Max(number1, number2);
        resultMax1 = Math.Max(resultMax1, number3);
        resultMax1 = Math.Max(resultMax1, number4);
        resultMax1 = Math.Max(resultMax1, number5);
        resultMax1 = Math.Max(resultMax1, number6);
        resultMax1 = Math.Max(resultMax1, number7);
        resultMax1 = Math.Max(resultMax1, number8);
        resultMax1 = Math.Max(resultMax1, number9);
        resultMax1 = Math.Max(resultMax1, number10);

        Console.WriteLine($"Максимальное значение в списке {resultMax1}") ;

        int resultMin1 = Math.Min(number1, number2);
        resultMin1 = Math.Min(resultMin1, number3);
        resultMin1 = Math.Min(resultMin1, number4);
        resultMin1 = Math.Min(resultMin1, number5);
        resultMin1 = Math.Min(resultMin1, number6);
        resultMin1 = Math.Min(resultMin1, number7);
        resultMin1 = Math.Min(resultMin1, number8);
        resultMin1 = Math.Min(resultMin1, number9);
        resultMin1 = Math.Min(resultMin1, number10);

        Console.WriteLine($"Минимальное значение с списке {resultMin1}");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    int min, max, greater = 0, lower = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Введите первое число");
    int number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    min = max = number1;
    greater += number1 > 10 ? 1 : 0;
    if (number1 < -10) lower++;

    ...

    Console.WriteLine("Введите Nое число");
    int numberN = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    min = Math.Min(min, numberN); // или min = numberN < min ? numberN : min;
    max = Math.Max(max, numberN); // или if (numberN > max) max = numberN;
    greater += numberN > 10 ? 1 : 0;
    if (numberN < -10) lower++;
```